# Check if array value is included in string

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on some client side validation for a contact form of sorts, the website currently isn't online so server side isn't relevant.

I am trying to create a 'word filter' to catch on any abusive of obscene language before the form is 'submitted'.

Heres the code, without the obscenities...

```
function filterInput(str) {
    var inputFilter = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3'];
    var arrayLength = inputFilter.length;

if (inputFilter.indexOf(str) > - 1) {
    // Word caught...
} else {
    // Clear...
}
```

If the user were to enter 'word1', it will catch the word. If the user enters 'word1word2' or 'John is a word3', it doesn't catch it.

I originally had a for loop which worked better, but still wouldn't work without whitespace between words('word1word2').

Any input would be greatly appreciated, I've been searching but nothing quite matches my needs.

EDIT: So I too have come up with a solution, but seeing the varying ways this can be achieved I am curious as to how it works and also why a particular way is better?

Heres what I came up with...

```
function filterInput(str) {
    var inputFilter = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3'];
    var arrayLength = inputFilter.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        if (str.includes(inputFilter[i])) {
            window.alert('Message...');
            return;
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) rather than `indexOf`, since you have to do custom matching:

```
if (inputFilter.some(function(word) { return str.indexOf(word) != -1; })) {
    // Word caught...
} else {
    // Clear...
}
```

Or with an ES2015+ arrow function and [`String.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```
if (inputFilter.some(word => str.includes(word))) {
    // Word caught...
} else {
    // Clear...
}
```

`some` calls the callback repeatedly until the first time it returns a truthy value. If the callback ever returns a truthy value, `some` returns `true`; otherwise, `some` returns `false`. E.g., it's asking if "some" of the entries match the predicate function. (`any` may have been a better term, but when adding to the built-ins, the TC39 committee have to do a lot of work to avoid conflicts with libraries and such.)

If you ever need to get back the actual entry, use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) which returns the entry or `undefined` if not found. If you need its index, use [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

---

Side note: Just beware that it's notoriously complicated to do this well. Beware of [the Scunthorpe problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem), and of course people will routinely just confuse the sequence of letters or substitute asterisks or similar to defeat filters of this sort...

Comment: I'm only starting out, so I think I'll avoid ES2015+ for now. As for some, how does it work in comparison to what I have come up with?

Comment: @mrkd1991: Not sure what you mean by "how does it work" there. If you mean performance, JavaScript engines are **very** fast at function calls. Here's an article I did on that back in 2012; even IE6, the slowest JavaScript engine you could ask for, did them so fast it wasn't a factor: http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2012/02/foreach-and-runtime-cost.html

Comment: As in, what does this function do to gain the desired outcome, and what's different between that and my new attempt?

Comment: @mrkd1991: I thought I explained how the above gets the outcome: *"`some` calls the callback repeatedly until the first time it returns a truthy value. If the callback ever returns a truthy value, some returns `true`; otherwise, some returns `false`."* So it looks for any entry where `str.indexOf(word) != -1` (or where `str.includes(word)` is true, in the ES2015+ version). That's what your code does with a `for` loop, just using `some` instead.

Comment: Your side note makes me think that as a beginner perhaps some isn't the best way to go, though normally it would be. Looking at the second function I created, (apart from not using some...)are there any issues or things that a begginer should perhaps do differently?

Comment: @mrkd1991: I don't see any reason not to use `some`. The side note is about the overall task, not whether you use `some` or a `for` loop. Re the code in the question: Looks just fine other than the missing `)` on the `if`.

Comment: Thanks for catching the missing bracket, I've updated the post. And apologies for seeming dumb, I hadn't taken the time to read about the Scunthorpe problem, so was misinterpreting what you meant. To be honest, this site will never go live, I am trying out new things trying to teach myself web development(for free). I'll definitely look into 'some' , as I only went with 'for' as it was the first solution I found that worked. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:-

```
function filterInput(str) {
  var badWords = ['bad', 'worst'];
  var isTrue = false;
  if(str) {
     for (var i = 0; i < badWords.length; i++) {
       isTrue = !!(str.replace(/\W|\s/g, '').toLowerCase().indexOf(badWords[i]) + 1);
       if(isTrue) break;
     }
  }
  return isTrue;
}
```

Comment: How would you compare using a boolean as opposed to the method I have used? Also, str is formatted before being passed so no need to do so within this function.