# How to acess innerText of each HTML element in an object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have an array with 9 elements wich are HTML elements as you can see in the picture below.

[Object array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN7CV.png)

I'am trying to create a function wich checks if there is any text inside each of those 9 elements

I have tried to run Array.ForEach method to check if there is an "X" inside the text ,  but I can't do it , maybe because Iam not sure how to acess the innerText of the propertie :

```
Board.SquaresArray.ForEach(function(){
```

if (Board.SquaresArray.InnerText =="X")
return console.log("This square has an X")};

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, data structures, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Would filter not wok here?

Comment: First of all, ForEach isn't spelled that way, it is camel-case: `forEach`. same with "InnerText"

Comment: See the [linked question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46526522/check-if-array-value-is-included-in-string) for details, but the short version is: `if (theArray.some(e => e.innerText)) {`

Comment: Assuming the object properties is what your are trying to filter for empty text try Object.entries + filter like recommended above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Board.SquaresArray` is a result of `document.querySellector()` or something like this, you need to convert it from `HTMLCollection` to Array:

`Array.from(Board.SquaresArray).some(el => el.innerText === 'X')`

Comment: `Board.SquaresArray` is a normal array not a collection.